# Where are mergers and acquisitions announced?

Tags: news

The Hasbro purchase of Entertainment One ETO at caught my eye.

What was the first outlet to release this news?

In general; are there a number of outlets that carry this type of information?

Since the news seems to carry quite a lot of value; how is "first access" to it controlled?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a company has corporate news, it makes a press release which is released  electronically and sometimes physically.  These are prepared ahead of time and the real time news organizations report it immediately (Dow Jones News, Bloomberg, Businesswire and other newswires, etc.).

Articles involving the interpretation of the corporate news tend to be delayed since the reporters at the outlets must collect information and write their story.